# Linking lists & sorting in python

Tags: python

Here's an example of what I want (Python 3.6):

```
List1= [1,2,3,4,5] #needed order
List2=[5,4,3,2,1] #inputted order.  
List3=[25,20,15,10,5] #order inputed linked with list2
```

Linked with `List3` in the same order

Expected output when `List2` is changed in order of `List1` or in order smallest to largest. `List3` would change too.

Desired output:

```
List2=[1,2,3,4,5] #list change to correct order
List3=[5,10,15,20,25] #list stayed in correct position linked with list2
```

Comment: You're looking for argsort functionality.

Comment: Is there any links or tutorial pages you have for this ? Or a example program?

Comment: `argsort` is part of the `numpy` package.

Comment: Is numpy built in ? To python

Comment: @GraphicsLab, you would benefit greatly by reading the python docs, and understanding many of [the functions in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).  Functions like `max`, `min`, `sorted`, `zip`, have very practical applications that you can use to combine into all sorts of things.  Read up on itertools and functools as well to get some ideas.

Comment: Cheers I know what min and max are so I’ll read up on the other things thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the argsort functionality. In python, one way to achieve this would be using `sorted` + `enumerate`:

```
>>> [List3[x] for x, _ in sorted(enumerate(List2), key=lambda x: x[1])]
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

---

With `numpy`, you'd be able to do this with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(List3)[np.argsort(List2)]
array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
```

Comment: Hi is there any way of doing this without downloading and install a package ?

Comment: @GraphicsLab The first technique does not require any packages.

Comment: Have you got an example of that please?

Comment: @GraphicsLab It's in my answer dude. `[List3[x] for x, _ in sorted(enumerate(List2), key=lambda x: x[1])]`

Comment: @GraphicsLab In the editor, you'll need to assign the return value of the expression to a variable and call `print`. `x = [.........]; print(x)` Seriously, just try it yourself.

Comment: @GraphicsLab While the other solution might look more elegant, one advantage with this is you can keep the sorted index to argsort any other list, you're not limited to sorting just two lists at a time, as in the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach of doing it in pure Python:

You zip the two lists, and then sort by first(default) element.

```
In [18]: List2=[5,4,3,2,1]

In [19]: List3=[25,20,15,10,5]

In [20]: [b for _, b in sorted(zip(List2, List3))]
Out[20]: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

If you wanted to sort by 2nd element you would do:

```
result = [b for _, b in sorted(zip(List2, List3), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Comment: I will try this what’s the bits with in [20]

Comment: @GraphicsLab, oh, I am using `ipython` interactive shell.

Comment: Okay mate so I just forget the first bits and just read after :

Comment: Beat me to it.  I think the sorted(zip ... solution is more elegant. :)

Comment: @GraphicsLab, Yeah, `Out [20]:` is part of the shell, ignore it.

Comment: Cheers I’ll have a try